# Sistema de ecuaciones NO lineales con números complejos

Tags: python-3.7, sympy, números-complejos

Estoy haciendome un pequeño código para resolver un circuito y la parte de resolver el sistema de ecuaciones no lineales con números complejos me falla y cuando me da un resultado no es el correcto.
Hasta el momento tengo lo siguiente:

```
    u6 = 1+0j
    s1 = 1+0j
   
    import sympy    
    #Variables simbolicas
    u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6 = sympy.symbols('u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6')
    vars=[u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6 ]
    

    #Sistema de ecuaciones no lineal
    F1 = sympy.re(zg*i6) + sympy.re(u6) - sympy.re(u5)
    F2 = sympy.re(i6) + sympy.re(u5*ytreq1) - sympy.re(i5)
    F3 = sympy.re(i5*ztreq1) + sympy.re(u5) - sympy.re(u4)
    F4 = sympy.re(i5) + sympy.re(u4*ypi) - sympy.re(i4)
    F5 = sympy.re(i4*zpi) + sympy.re(u4) - sympy.re(u3)
    F6 = sympy.re(i4) + sympy.re(2*ypi*u3) - sympy.re(i3)
    F7 = sympy.re(i3*zpi) + sympy.re(u3) - sympy.re(u2)
    F8 = sympy.re(i3) + sympy.re(ypi*u2) - sympy.re(i2)
    F9 = sympy.re(i2*ztreq1) + sympy.re(u2) - sympy.re(u1)
    F10 = sympy.re(i2) + sympy.re(u1*ytreq1) - sympy.re(i1)
    F11 = sympy.re(u1*i1.conjugate()) - sympy.re(s1)

    F12 = sympy.im(zg*i6) + sympy.im(u6) - sympy.im(u5)
    F13 = sympy.im(i6) + sympy.im(u5*ytreq1) - sympy.im(i5)
    F14 = sympy.im(i5*ztreq1) + sympy.im(u5) - sympy.im(u4)
    F15 = sympy.im(i5) + sympy.im(u4*ypi) - sympy.im(i4)
    F16 = sympy.im(i4*zpi) + sympy.im(u4) - sympy.im(u3)
    F17 = sympy.im(i4) + sympy.im(2*ypi*u3) - sympy.im(i3)
    F18 = sympy.im(i3*zpi) + sympy.im(u3) - sympy.im(u2)
    F19 = sympy.im(i3) + sympy.im(ypi*u2) - sympy.im(i2)
    F20 = sympy.im(i2*ztreq1) + sympy.im(u2) - sympy.im(u1)
    F21 = sympy.im(i2) + sympy.im(u1*ytreq1) - sympy.im(i1)
    F22 = sympy.im(u1*i1.conjugate()) - sympy.im(s1)
    system = [F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,F11,F12,F13,F14,F15,F16,F17,F18,F19,F20,F21,F22]

    #Resolucion del sistema
    z = sympy.solve(system,vars)  #me devuelve una lista gigantesca formada por un diccionario
    return z
```

u6, s6, todas las z's e y's son valores complejos y conocidos.
¿Alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal o no estoy teniendo en cuenta? Estoy bastante desesperada porque he probado con todo (sympy, spicy, numpy) y no consigo resolver el sistema ni obtener la solución correcta.
¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo del tipo de sistema de ecuaciones que necesitas resolver? ¿Has probado con https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html ?

Comment: El sistema es algo así:
    u5 = zg*i6 + u6
    i5 = i6 + u5*ytr
    u4 = i5*ztr + u5
    i4 = i5 + u4*ypi
    u3 = zpi*i4 + u4
    i3 = i4 + 2*ypi*u3
    u2 = i3*zpi + u3
    i2 = i3 + u2*ypi
    u1 = ztr*i2 + u2
    i1 = i2 + u1*ytr
    s1 = u1*i1.conjugate()
He probado con todo y no me funciona.

Comment: No ha salido muy legible la ecuación en el comentario. De todas formas veo que es una ecuación simbólica. Dices que sympy no te lo ha resuelto bien? ¿Será que no entiende la i como parte la notación compleja ya la considera otra variable?

Comment: Esto tal vez te sea útil: [How to solve complex equations in two variables in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996768/how-to-solve-complex-equations-in-two-variables-in-python)